# Extend root partition space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

I am kind of new to ubuntu, and during the installation of it I made the mistake of assigning little space to the root partition (/), but a huge one to the home (/home).
I thought that it was going to be as easy as in Windows to extend the space of one partition, sike!, it is not.

Is there any way I could increase my root partition (/) with the all the unallocated space I freeded ? Any tutorial or so to follow ?

[image: gparted screenshot]

Comment: _sudo parted -l_ (where l is a lowercase L not a 1) makes a partition list far easier to read than screenshots. Screenshots are less popular here since they are often harder to read. That being said, if you boot from a LiveUSB of Ubuntu you will be able to move the root partition AFTER TAKING PRECAUTIONS. Please make a backup to a different drive of everything you don't want to lose and verify (checksums work well) the backup is accurate, then make another backup to yet another drive or the cloud and verify that. Changing partitions is the easiest way without a sledgehammer to lose data!

Comment: The suggested procedure "Option 2" in the link provided explains how.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to return here to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: this is why it's not a good idea to multi-partition a small HDD/SSD

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/sdb2 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sdb2 all the way right*

  - however, that'll make /dev/sdb2 ~120G, and that's really too big for /
  - **resize** /dev/sdb2 such that it's about 30-50G, and leave the rest for /dev/sdb4 (/home), which can be resized later
- click the Apply icon

Comment: So sorry for the delay, had so much work to do and did not have a backup done beforehand, thereby it took me longer than expected. Your solution worked perfectly ! Thank you so much, and again, I am so sorry for the delay.

Comment: @aitor1skater Great news! Please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!